# Simple html divs lining "bug"

Tags: html, css

So i have this rather strange issue, i am trying to line up some `divs` but i came across this strange problem. Let's say if i put `<input type="checkbox" />` inside a div and would try to line it in the same line as other div it wouldn't work no matter what i try but if i add some text to the second div it suddenly start to work, why is that happening?

Here is example of my code to make thing a bit clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/wxgVw/2/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="left">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <div id="right">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body{
    margin:50px;
}

#container{
    width:770px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#container2{
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    padding:10px;
}

#left{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}

#right{
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Put a copy of your code in your question.  Anyone can change a fiddle at any time; future existence of the fiddle is not guaranteed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought the "run" button just updates the Result tab with your changes, and the "Update" button branches off a new version (hence the `/2/`, `/3/` and so on on the URL)...

Comment: @Kolink: Alright.  But we have the ability to post code here; we shouldn't rely solely on links to outside sources for that.

Comment: Any reason why you're doing all the `display inline` stuff when `float` works?  http://jsfiddle.net/wxgVw/5/

Comment: Although Kolink is technically correct about jsFiddle, I agree with RobertHarvey.  Questions should be fully self-contained, otherwise they're totally useless when the demo links go dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use `display: inline-block` it is always a good idea to also specify `vertical-align: top` (or `bottom` depending on what you want). That would prevent this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the float property. Just float both divs to the left and make sure overflow: hidden is set to to container above to prevent floating issues.

I edited your sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/wxgVw/4/

```
#container2{
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid green;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: +1, This is the way I'd do it... a lot less CSS and a lot more predictable.